# Mobile app is very slow while fetching the data

Tags: android, configuration, server

Our mobile app is very slow. We have developed an app in which we do not perform any e-commerce but we interact with database in terms of creating categories (about 20), adding stores (about 100), add products with product description & 2 images in slider (1000).

Looking for suggestions about server configuration and best practices.

Thank you in advance..

Comment: You need to provide some more information. Do some research (like profiling on app and the database) on the slowness reasons and provide us with specific code sections where you feel you are slow. I'm sure you'll get help with that. ATB.

Comment: Have you tried to fetch smaller fixed number of object(ie like 20 stores) in each request rather than fetching all shop object at once and then fetch more shop as user scrolls or slides. But this will increase the number of request to server when large number of users are using the app.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. can you suggest best server configuration for ecommerce mobile app.